# error message asking for Properties onMetaData when load external vdo BUT, vdo can play anyway

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, error-handling, external

I'm trying to figure out how to remove the message error and what cause it. 
I created a code for loading external vdo to play on Flash. Coding it inside the Action Script panel is fine so I try to make it as a class. I moved all the code and put it in a class and it works fine too. But, the error message appeared ! even though the file could play correctly.
The error says:

> Error #2044: Unhandled AsyncErrorEvent:. text=Error #2095: flash.net.NetStream was unable to invoke callback onMetaData. error=ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property onMetaData not found on vdoloader and there is no default value.
>       at vdoloader()

This is my code

```
package  {

import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.NetStream;
import flash.media.Video;   

public class vdoloader extends Sprite {
    var video;
    var nc;
    var ns;

    public function vdoloader() {
        // constructor code
        nc = new NetConnection();
        nc.connect(null);
        ns = new NetStream(nc);
        ns.client=this;
        video = new Video(550,400);
        addChild (video);
        video.attachNetStream(ns);
        ns.play("westler.flv"); 
    }
}
}
```

And then I tried to put something in that `vdoloader()`, it said something like: "expected 1, got 0."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is exactly that - you are not handling the meta data event by implementing a function onMetaData. The client of your player is "this", so you should have a public function onMetaData in your class.

An please oh please, use an uppercase first letter for your class name...

EDIT:
In your code you are assigning `this` as the netstream's client (source: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html):

> Associate a client property with an event handler to receive the data
>   object. Use the NetStream.client property to assign an object to call
>   specific data handling functions. The object assigned to the
>   NetStream.client property can listen for the following data points:
>   onCuePoint(), onImageData(), onMetaData(), onPlayStatus(),
>   onSeekPoint(), onTextData(), and onXMPData(). Write procedures within
>   those functions to handle the data object returned from the stream
>   during playback. See the NetStream.client property for more
>   information.

So now you just need to create a function onMetaData(md:Object) that should handle the event within the very same class, i.e. vdoloader (<=as you are passing `this` as the client). You can check the docs how to do it: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetStream.html#event:onMetaData. I *think* that Lee Brimelow had a tutorial about this on his site - http://www.gotoandlearn.com. (I am not sure about this but I guess it is worth a try if you are interested)

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to the class programming. I will use an uppercase now.

About onMetaData you said, I don't really understand what to do next. If I create a public function onMetaDa(){ <<like this, then what next?

I'm so sorry that I don't get your advice quick. Can you please tell  me more about it or at least where to read about this issue??

Thanks again.